# JasperReports create two columns and two rows

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to get my way around JasperReports but I can seem to understand the simple tutorials that I am getting from the net.

Here's what I want.  I wanted to generate a  2 columns 2 rows report wherein I will send the data in the jrxml file. But I cant seem to get past the compiler. It says `element bottom reaches outside band area`.  I thought I already set the height to 100 and the height of the reportelement is only 24.

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
    name="Report" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0">

    <detail>
        <band height="100">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
                <textElement/>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Column Number 1: ]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="79" height="24" />
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Column  Number 2: ]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="100">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="200" width="69" height="24" />
                <textElement/>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Column Number 3: ]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="200" width="79" height="24" />
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Column  Number 4: ]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I am not sure is it considered illegal to have two band tag in one detail tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest downloading [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) and use it to build your report.

It is a full functioning application for designing jasper reports.

If you in fact open your existing jrxml file it should highlight in red where you're out of bounds in your bands.

**Edit:**

The reason you are getting the error is the x and y coordinates in the jasper report are relative to the band not the page. So a value y 200 put it outside the band.

If you use the same values that are used in your first band it should work fine, e.g.

`<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24" />` for both.

Comment: @Mark Estrada Glad to help. Please see the elaborated answer. It should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

or jasperAssisstant, if you are using Eclipse. They are perfect tools for Jasper Design, else, modifying directly on the jrxml, remembering all the tags, is very tedious.